# How can I select shapes without their connector lines?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Say I have 10 rectangles connected by 9 arrow lines and I want to distribute them vertically.

What is the quickest way to select the rectangles without selecting the lines?

Answer (score 1):

There are not that many ways to select in PowerPoint:

- It seems like the method of doing Ctrl+click on each shape is too tiresome
- The rectangles might be arranged in such a way that dragging
  a selection rectangle around them will fully include the rectangles
  but exclude the lines (by only partially including them)
- Using the Selection Pane via
  *Home > Drawing group > Arrange* and selecting
  "Selection Pane" will show all the elements on the right, with the
  rectangles usually named "Rectangle #", so they are easier to pick out.
  However, multi-select is still by Ctrl+click.
- Write a VBA macro to select all rectangles is more complicated.

Comment: I feared as much. Is there maybe a setting to change the selection mode to only have to enclose objects partially instead of fully? That's a mode I am used to from e.g. Factorio and other applications, and would solve many common use cases (like when all rectangles are in a line).

Comment: Unfortunately this option doesn't exist. If this is a recurring operation, you could use the add-in of [PPTools Selection Manager](http://www.pptools.com/free/FAQ00003-Selection-Manager.htm).